Unusual limit in solving electrostatics for point charge above conducting plane
I was trying to solve the following problem without using image charges:
A point charge $q$ is put at distance $d$ above an infinte conducting plane. Determine the induced surface charge density $\sigma$.
Let us consider the total electric field below the plane. Since we are inside a conductor the total field must be zero. Therefore if we calculate the z component of the electric field due to the point charge we get:
$$E_z=\frac{-kq(d-z)}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2+(z-d)^2}^3}$$
on the other hand the field due to the induced surface charge is
$$E_{i,z}=-kz\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{\sigma (x',y')dx'dy'}{\sqrt{(x-x')^2+(y-y')^2+z^2}^3}$$
with a change of variables $u,v=x-x',y-y'$, using polar coordinates after this substitution and using the fact that by symmetry the surface charge can only be a function of r I get the following 1-variable integral:
$$E_{i,z}=-2\pi kz\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{\sigma(r)rdr}{\sqrt{r^2+z^2}^3}$$
Now my idea: I wanted to consider a point very close to the surface of the plane, that is i wanted to use $E_z+E_{i,z}=0$ in the limit $z\to 0$. So I'd like to evaluate $$\lim_{z\to 0}\left(-2\pi kz\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{\sigma(r)rdr}{\sqrt{r^2+z^2}^3}\right)$$ If my previous calculations contain no mistake I should get $-2\pi k\sigma(0)$ from this limit which is equivalent to $-2\pi k\sigma(x,y)$. How should I evaluate the limit?

The sum of the normal component of elecrtic field is not zero at the upper surface of the plate. In fact, Gauss's law implies that the normal component of electric field is equal to the surface charge density divided by the vacuum permittivity.  Please see my solution herein.

And feel free to accept an answer as you see fit.

I hope that you are doing well. I have provided a solution and wanted you to know that you may feel free to accept an answer as you see fit

The electric field at a point $(\rho,z)$, $z>0$ due to the surface charge density $\sigma(\rho)$ on the plane $z=0$ is given by
$$\begin{align}
\vec E_2(\rho,z)&=\frac1{4\pi \varepsilon_0}\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^\infty \frac{\sigma(\rho+\rho')(\hat zz-\hat \rho'\rho')}{(\rho'^2+z^2)^{3/2}}\,\rho'\,d\rho'\,d\phi'\\\\
&=\hat z z\frac{1}{2 \varepsilon_0}\int_0^\infty \frac{\rho' \sigma(\rho+\rho')}{(\rho'^2+z^2)^{3/2}}\,dz
\end{align}$$
Now, we let $z\to 0^+$. For any given number $\varepsilon>0$, we can find a number $\delta>0$ such that whenever $0<\rho'<\delta$, we have $|\sigma(\rho+\rho')-\sigma(\rho)|<\varepsilon$.  So, for this $\varepsilon$ and $\delta$, we can write
$$\begin{align}
\vec E_2(\rho,z)&=\hat z z\frac{1}{2 \varepsilon_0}\int_0^\delta \frac{\rho' (\sigma(\rho+\rho')-\sigma(\rho))}{(\rho'^2+z^2)^{3/2}}\,d\rho'\\\\
&+\frac{\hat zz\sigma(\rho)}{2\varepsilon_0}\left(\frac1z-\frac1{\sqrt{\delta^2+z^2}}\right)\\\\
&+\hat z z\frac{1}{2 \varepsilon_0}\int_\delta^\infty \frac{\rho' \sigma(\rho+\rho')}{(\rho'^2+z^2)^{3/2}}\,d\rho'\tag1
\end{align}$$
It is easy to see that the limit as $z\to 0^+$ of the second and third terms on the right-hand side of $(1)$ sum to $\hat z\frac{\sigma(\rho)}{2\varepsilon_0}$.  For the first term, we note that
$$\left|\hat z z\frac{1}{2 \varepsilon_0}\int_0^\delta \frac{\rho' (\sigma(\rho+\rho')-\sigma(\rho))}{(\rho'^2+z^2)^{3/2}}\,d\rho'\right|< \frac{z\varepsilon}{2\varepsilon_0}\left(\frac1z-\frac1{\sqrt{\delta^2+z^2}}\right)\tag2$$
As $z\to 0^+$, the term on the right-hand side of $(2)$ approaches $\frac{\varepsilon}{2\varepsilon_0}$.  Inasmuch as $\varepsilon>0$ is arbitrary, we find that
$$\lim_{z\to 0^+}\vec E_z(\rho,z)=\hat z\frac{\sigma(\rho)}{2\varepsilon_0}\tag3$$
Finally, to find the charge density $\sigma(\rho)$ on a conducting plate at $z=0$ induced by a point charge at $\rho=0$ and $z=d>0$ we use the boundary condition from Gauss's law, $E_z(\rho, z=0^+)=\frac{\sigma(\rho)}{\epsilon_0}$.
Then, we see that
$$\frac{\sigma(\rho)}{2\varepsilon_0}+\frac{-qd}{4\pi\varepsilon_0(\rho^2+d^2)}=\frac{\sigma(\rho)}{\varepsilon_0}$$
from which we arrive at the coveted result
$$\sigma(\rho)=-\frac{qd}{2\pi (\rho^2+d^2)^{3/2}}$$
And we are done!

@edoRoundTheWorld Please let me know how I can improve my answer. I really want to give you the best answer I can.

Hi, you have to excuse me I was sure I had replied to your answer, it is clear now thank you!

@EdoRoundTheWorld Pleased to hear.

@edoroundtheworld I hope that you are doing well. I have provided a solution and wanted you to know that you may feel free to accept an answer as you see fit.
